# "être perdu" vs "se perdre" ?

Tags: grammaire, choix-de-mot

I saw the sentence in Asterix:

> Qui osera dire encore que l'art du camouflage se perd dans la legion romaine ?

Would this variant be wrong? What's the difference?

> Qui osera dire encore que l'art du camouflage est perdu dans la legion romaine ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In the first case, the camouflage art is in the process of being lost while in the second one, it has already been lost.

Comment: But then what would be the difference between *s'est perdu* and *est perdu* ?

Comment: Assuming you are talking about someone, in the second case, the person might not have been active in the process of being lost.

Comment: If talking about camouflage: *s'est perdu* : it has been lost in the past while *est perdu* : it is lost now.

Comment: "s'est perdu" implies that it *specifically was a specialty* in the legion, and also that is lost to the legion specifically, but not necessarily to society at large.

Comment: "Etre perdu" means gone, lost. "Se perdre" would mean fade away, let go with the idea it is slowly getting to the point of being totally lost. The second will lead to the first if nothing changes in the situation.